# Opposite Symmetric Monoidal Structure on an Infinity Category

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

Given an $\infty$-category (in the sense of Lurie) $C$, and a symmetric monoidal structure on $C$ associated to a coCartesian fibration $p:C^\otimes\to N(Fin_\ast)$, Lurie says in Remark 2.4.2.7 of Higher Algebra that by identifying $C$ with a functor $N(Fin_\ast)\to Cat_\infty$ and composing with the involution $R:Cat_\infty\to Cat_\infty$, $C\mapsto C^{op}$, we can induce a symmetric monoidal structure on $C^{op}$ induced from that of $C$ which is unique up to contractible ambiguity (I'm fudging some details here, like the fact that this involution is actually defined on a different but equivalent category).

My question is the following: Let $C$ be a symmetric monoidal category. I want to consider the category of commutative algebras in $C^{op}$ (using the induced symmetric monoidal structure described above), $CAlg(C^{op})$. This category admits a symmetric monoidal structure of its own (see Remark 3.2.4.4 of Lurie's Higher Algebra). Thus, we can again take opposites to obtain a symmetric monoidal category $CoCAlg(C)\equiv(CAlg(C^{op})^{op})$. Let $\star$ denote the finally induced symmetric monoidal structure on $CoCAlg(C)$. Is it true that for $X$ and $Y$ objects of $CoCAlg(C)$,  $X\star Y\simeq X\otimes Y$ where $\otimes$ is the original symmetric monoidal structure on $C$? If so, is there an easy way to prove this? It seems like a pretty reasonable thing to expect.

Comment: Isn't it true that the forgetful functor $CAlg(C)\to C$ is symmetric monoidal. In that case the functor $CoCAlg(C)\to C$ is symmetric monoidal as well which is what you want.

Comment: Hi Jon, I think Example 3.2.4.4 from HA tells you what you need to know. By the way, there's no Remark 3.4.2.2 in the version that's online now, are you looking at another one?

Comment: Whoops, I actually meant 3.2.4.4. But, alright, I'll look more closely at that one.

Comment: Oh, and hi @GijsHeuts! Hope you're doing well! :-)

Comment: Jeez, sorry, you guys are right. It's that evaluation functor that Lurie describes in that very Remark. Somehow I was just not reading that part thoroughly.

Comment: This is all perhaps a summary of what's been said so far, but the evaluation functor that's a map of ∞-operads is symmetric monoidal, so you get the required result.

Comment: @RingSpectra yes! Would you care to expand on that and make it an answer?

Comment: @Jon See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I think it's important to notice one thing: if there is a cocartesian fibration of $\infty$-operads $C^\otimes\to Fin_\ast$ determining a symmetric monoidal structure on an $\infty$-category $C$, it is *not* the opposite fibration which determines the symmetric monoidal structure on $C^{op}$. In other words, there really *isn't* a cocartesian fibration $C^{\otimes,op}\to Fin_\ast$ that does what we want. The way to get this is to use [a recent paper of Barwick, Glassman and Nardin](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.2165.pdf) that produces the *dual* cartesian fibration $C^{\otimes,\vee}\to Fin_\ast^{op}$ and *then* apply $op$, to obtain a cocartesian fibration $(C^{\otimes,\vee})^{op}\to Fin_\ast$ (sorry for all of the decorations). Anyway, it's this fibration whose fiber over $\langle n\rangle$ is $(C^{op})^n$ and which classifies the composite functor $op\circ C^\otimes:Fin_\ast\to Cat_\infty$.

Anyway, following up with Gijs, Sanath and Geoffrey's comments, I'll say the following as a final answer:

Following Remark 3.2.4.4 of Higher Algebra, we have that if $C$ is symmetric monoidal then the forgetful functor $U:CAlg(C)^\otimes\to C$ (given by evaluation on $\langle 1\rangle\in Fin_\ast$) is itself a symmetric monoidal functor, indicating that if $\Box$ is the symmetric monoidal structure on $Alg(C)$ then $U(A\Box B)\simeq A\otimes B$, where $\otimes$ is the symmetric monoidal structure on $C$. So, for us, this means that there is a forgetful functor whcih is also symmetric monoidal $CAlg(C^{op})\to C^{op}$ which which shows that tensor products in $CAlg(C^{op})$ are computed the same way tensor products in $C^{op})$ are.

This of course doesn't quite give us the solution rigorously, since there's no way to get from $C^{op}$ back to $C$, and we would like an honest equivalence. Thus, we have to use the fact that since we have put a symmetric monoidal structure on $CAlg(C^{op})$ given by $CAlg(C^{op})^\otimes\to Fin_\ast$, we can produce a cocartesian fibration (again using the technology described above) $(CAlg(C^{op})^{\otimes,\vee})^{op}\to Fin_\ast$ whose fiber over $\langle n\rangle$ is $(CAlg(C^{op})^{op})^n$. *Then* we note that there is a forgetful functor down to $C^\otimes$ and since none of the above constructions change any of the important structure *fiberwise*, we have an equivalence of the forgetful map applied to the tensor of two coalgebras with their tensor in $C$.

Comment: Is it true that, with your notations, $CAlg((C^{\otimes,\vee})^{op})\simeq CAlg(C^\otimes)^{op}$?